# height equal width responsive on resize javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this script I want to put my height as big as my width. This works if you shrink your browser and then refresh your browser. But now I want him to do it when I resize the browser without having to refresh. Have tried to resize window but it didn't worked, perhaps i used it wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var height = $('.circle img').width();
    $('.circle img').css({ 'height': height + 'px' });
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you included the jquery library on your top of head tag and your code be inside the document.ready function()

Comment: Can you show the html for circle and img? There may be an easy pure css solution

Comment: <div class="circle">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/headerimg.png">
</div>

Comment: for a CSS solution, you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attach a resize event handler with jQuery [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var height = $('.circle img').width();
   $('.circle img').css({'height':height+'px'});
});
```

Comment: @StefanieSmet, are there any errors? Check the console

Comment: @StefanieSmet, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: Only this: Using getPreventDefault () is no longer supported. Instead of that use defaultPrevented. But I don't think it has something to do with this?!

Comment: @StefanieSmet, it may depending on sequence of events in your page

Comment: i think this is the fiddle but you don't see the image 
https://jsfiddle.net/t9407879/1/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using **vw** ([viewport width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)) instead of **px** to determine your width instead? 
If it's possible for the design of your site, you can use pure CSS instead of Javascript to keep the aspect ratio consistent.

It goes a little something like this:

```
.circle img {
   width: 10vw;
   height: 10vw;
}
```